# Proving that the absolute value of a function is continuous if the function itself is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I would like to prove that if the function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and the function $|f| : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $|f|(x) = |f(x)|$ for all $x$, then the function $|f| : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is also continuous.

I think that the correct way to do to this is to use the fact that for two functions $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(D)$ is contained in $U$, the composition of functions, $g \circ f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

So, does that mean to prove my original assertion, I should introduce a new function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined and $g : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = |x|$. Then, I should prove that $f$ and $g$ are continuous, and by the continuity of composition of functions, I can conclude that $g \circ f$ is continuous, which completes my proof?

I don't know if $f$ and $g$ should be defined on $D$, though. I believe that now I just need to show $g$ is continuous to complete my proof.

Could someone please help me check this method, and help me with this exercise? This isn't a homework problem, I'd just like to learn some analysis on my own.

---

**My attempt at the proof:**
First of all, here is the definition of continuity that I am following:

*Definition:* A function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be *continuous at the point $x_{0}$ in $D$* provided that whenever $\{x_{n}\}$ is a sequence in $D$ that converges to $x_{0}$, the image sequence $\{f(x_{n}\}$ converges to $f(x_{0})$. The function is said to be *continuous* provided that it is continuous everywhere in $D$.

---

**Lemma 1**: The function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = |x|$ is continuous.

**Proof of Lemma 1:** Select a point $x_{0}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence that converges to $x_{0}$. Then,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}|x_{n}| = |x_{0}| = f(x_{0}).$$

So, $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$.

**Proof of Assertion**: Let $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions, where $g(x) = |x|$. By our assumption, $f$ is continuous. Also, by Lemma $1$, $g$ is continuous. Therefore, by the continuity of composite functions, $(g \circ f)(x)$ is also continuous. This completes our proof.

Comment: $f$ should be $f$, not $f(x)=x$.

Comment: sorry, I am confused by what you mean by this

Comment: Hint: Reverse triangle inequality

Comment: Your idea is the right one.  However, with YOUR choices of $f$ and $g$, the composition $g \circ f$ is just $(g \circ f)(x) = |x|$.  You want to get $|f(x)|$ as an output instead.

Comment: Oh, so if I let $f = f$ and $g = |x|$, then $g \circ f$ becomes $|f(x)|$. I understand that part now, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: By our assumption, $f$ is continuous. This makes it even easier right? Now I just need to show $|x|$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, you got it again.  This is the absolute simplest way to do this, by far.

Comment: I didn't intend the pun, but I'll let it lie.

Comment: Would it be okay if I showed that $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = |x|$ is continuous? Or does it need to be more general? Because the question says defines $|f|$ from $D$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and I assume that $D$ is some arbitrary domain.

Comment: Yep. Restrictions of continuous functions are continuous.

Comment: Could you please check my attempt at the proof? I edited my original post with it. I have also included the definition of continuity that I am working with for your reference. If there is anything that I can improve, please let me know. Also, if you make a post, I will give you correct answer

Answer (score 2):

To show that $|f(x)|$ is continuous at a point $x=a$ we need to show that given an $\epsilon>0$, there exist a $\delta $ such that $$ |x-a| <\delta \implies  ||f(x)|-|f(a)||<\epsilon$$

Since $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ for the given $\epsilon$ we have a  $\delta$ such that $$ |x-a| <\delta \implies  |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$

Note that  if $$ |x-a| <\delta$$ then  $$ ||f(x)|-|f(a)||\le |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon $$

Comment: I am trying to solve this problem using the sequential definition of continuity. I updated my post with it.